# Inner Join

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$query4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE content_id = '$id' AND     content = 'thread'
                  INNER JOIN users ON comments.poster = users.id
                  ORDER BY comments.date ASC");
while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($query4)) {
}
```

all the tables and columns exist and i am connected to the database but it still gives me:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in thread.php on line 63
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do NOT use content_id='$id'. It is vulnerable to sql-injection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your join syntax is wrong. Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
INNER JOIN users ON comments.pooster = users.id
WHERE comments.content_id = '$id'
ORDER BY comments.date ASC
```